# Circular dependency for extracted styles with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, styled-components, circular-dependency

I’m fairly new to styled-components and trying to extract / refactor styles to separate files. I have problem with circular dependency - probably because of lacks of experience in styled-components good practices.
This is the situation:

```
// A.js
import { StyledA } from './styles';

export default () => (
  <StyledA>
    <SomeOtherComponent />
  </StyledA>
);

// B.js
import { StyledA1 } from './styles';

export default () => (
   <SomeWrapperComponent>
     <StyledA1 />
   </SomeWrapperComponent>
);

// styles.js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import A from './A.js';

export const StyledA = styled.div`...`;
export const StyledA1 = styled(A)`...`; // causes dependency circle error
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is to extend `A` component styles and keep it's children components (for file `B.js`).

- `export const StyledA1 = styled(StyledA)` doesn't work because I lose component `A` structure.
- ...and import `A` in `styles.js` causes eslint "dependency-cycle" error because of imports `A.js → styles.js → A.js`.

What should I do to keep HTML structure of extended component and resolve dependency cycle issue?

Comment: Firstly, can you reproduce the error in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)? Secondly, if you want to re-use styles such **way is not a good practice**, if you have specific problems you trying to solve and looking for a recommendation please explain it and show examples.

Comment: Well, in sandbox this "dependency cycle" error doesn't appear and everything works fine - maybe because of standard eslint configuration (my project uses `Airbnb` config). Anyway, this is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-voice-pf9ni). In `components/B.js` file you can see (commented out) code before extracting styles to separate file.

Comment: I will add an answer of a good practice example, you never export `styled` components, see it as a workaround solution instead of trying to fix this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

When working with CSS-in-JS (like `styled-components`) you **usually keep the components generated by `style` in the same file**.

So how do you export the `className` generated with CSS-in-JS constructor? By using **compound components**.

```
export const StyledA = styled.div`
  background: red;
  font-size: 20px;
`;

const A = ({ className }) => (
  <StyledA className={className}>
    <div>Display me always!</div>
  </StyledA>
);

// Can use any naming here
A.className = StyledA;

export default A;
```

Also, when you want to **reuse styles**, you create file like `styles.js` and declare reusable `css` blocks:

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

const border = css`
  border: 2px black solid;
`;

export { border };
```

Full usage:

```
import A from './components/A';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { border } from './components/styles';

const StyledA = styled(A)`
  background-color: palevioletred;
`;

const StyledASelector = styled.div`
  ${A.className} {
    background-color: paleturquoise;
    margin: 5px;
    ${border}
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <A />
      <StyledA />
      <StyledASelector>
        <A />
      </StyledASelector>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit interesting-heyrovsky-sgujh]

Comment: Well, previously I had most of the styles in the same JS file but I heard this is a bad practise keeping everything together. I found this [topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/a4a172/what_is_the_best_project_structure_for/) and started extracting styles - I relied on [Spectrum repo](https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/tree/alpha/src/components), where styled component are in separate style files. What about this repo then?

Comment: Everything in React is opinioned, there is no standard, it is the **first time** I see such example like in the spectrum repo. Pick 10 highly rated repos and check their opinions. Also, it is a **first time** I see components with 500 lines like in this repo.